# How do I get validation to play nice with assessors and mutators in Laravel 4 eloquent models?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, eloquent

I have a table which has a field I want to encrypt for extra protection.

Lets call the table "locker". It has two relevent fields:

```
name varchar(64)
pin varchar(64)
```

In this invented example, the pin is 4 digits but I want to store it encrypted.

I have created accessors and mutators to do just this, and they work fine. I have included the code below.

```
class Locker extends BaseModel
{
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $rules = ['name' => 'required'];

public function getPinAttribute($value)
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($value);
}


public function setPinAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['pin'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
}

}
```

And the basemodel itself is as follows:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

protected $rules = array();
protected $errors;

public static function boot()
{
parent::boot();
static::saving(function($model)
{
    return $model->validate();
});
}


public function validate()
{

    $data = $this->getAttributes();
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

    // check for failure
    if ($v->fails())
    {
        // set errors and return false
        $this->errors = $v->errors();
        return false;
    }

    // validation pass
    return true;
}

public function getErrors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}
}
```

However, I also want to perform validation. To do that I add the following:

```
protected $rules = ['name' => 'required','pin' => 'required|numeric'];
```

Now, the validation fails. Presumably what is happening is that the mutator is kicking in before the validation occurs.

My question is simple, how do I validate the data before I mutate it? I know I can fudge it, but whats the (or a) correct way to do it?

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that you are trying to validate it just before saving it to the database. I am not in a place where I can test this out but, can you try to call `parent::boot` after you define the saving method?

Comment: No joy I'm afraid, I moved parent::boot below the saving method and it still wouldn't play dice. It fails the numeric validation.